# How can I know when ajax loaded content finished?

Tags: jquery, html

I am loading HTML using AJAX,  in the main page I have two divs (one is on the left side called `home-logo`, the other is called `home-copy`), AJAX will load content fit into the div `home-copy`,  but content of each page are different. How do I get the height of each content then set this height to `home-copy.height`?

```
function handleAjax(e) { 
    // get the page we want 
    getPage = $(this).attr('href'); 
    // make AJAX call 
    $.get('ajax.php', {page: getPage}, function(data) { 
        result = $.parseJSON(data); 
        // fill in new page 
        $('#subnav').html(result.subnav); 
        $('#home-copy').html(result.copy);
        // get document height and get rid of 15% minus the height of the boxes and padding 
        docHeight = [$(document).height()-($(document).height()*.15)]-100; 

        // change height of content boxes 
        $('#home-logo').animate({height: docHeight}, 0); 
        $('#home-copy').animate({
            height: docHeight, 
            backgroundColor: 'white', 
            color: 'gray', 
            paddingTop: 50
        }, 0); 
        // fade out the footer 
        $('#footer-row').fadeOut(); 
        // change background 
        //$('#content-area').backstretch(result.background); 
        $('#background img').attr("src",result.background); 

        // clear old nav 
        $('.current_page_item_green').removeClass('current_page_item_green'); 
        $('.current_page_item').removeClass('current_page_item'); 

        // update navigation 
        if (result.nav_color == 'green') { 
            // add green 
            $('.nav-link').each(function() { 
                $(this).addClass('green'); 
            }); 
            $(result.current_page_item).addClass('current_page_item_green'); 
        } else { 
            $('.nav-link').each(function() { 
                $(this).removeClass('green'); 
            }); 
            $(result.current_page_item).addClass('current_page _item'); 
        } 
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're already specifying a function that gets called on success of the AJAX call.  You may want to use the `ajax` method instead of `get`, though, since you get more granularity in how you deal with configuration and failure.

Answer (score 2):

use ajax `success` function

like

```
success: function (dataCheck) {
                // code after success 
                }
```

or by using `done` method like

Example: Save some data to the server and notify the user once it's complete.

```
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "some.php",
         data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
      }).done(function( msg ) 
       {
         alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
      });
```

Comment: hi Nikola,  I still can't get it.  what should I put after the success:?

Comment: I'm confused.  Isn't he effectively doing this already with the third argument to his `get` call?